# Android: Spotify authentication doesn't work on Android 6.0 when installed via Playstore

Tags: android, authentication, httprequest, spotify, spotify-app

I'm developing a Spotify-app on Android. The app already runs on Nougat and Oreo, but I'm still having problems with Android 6.0.
The Problem is if I install the app via Playstore, I'm stuck on the loading screen because I don't receive a correct response. 
But now, if I install the exact same app from Android Studio, it works without any problems. This also makes debugging very difficult, because I can't use the debugger for Playstore apps.

Do you have any Ideas why? I've got the same problem on all 3 devices that run Android 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an answer for that, but I can't even get that far. Which Spotify API are you using? If you're able to get it to get that far, I may have hope haha

Comment: I'm using the official Spotify Android SDK Authentication API and the Spotify web API wrapper from Kaaes for android, but I believe I'm stuck in the authentication process. It's difficult to say because I don't own any 
Android Marshmallow phone and my virtual machine runs just fine. The app goes so far the it opens the login window, but I think, I don't receive a response

Comment: I don't receive a correct response from Spotify. Is it possible that the sha1 hash changed in prenougat, that I need for the Spotify developer site? 

Btw I receive the code from SpotifyAuth. and then do an HTTP request to my webpage to get refresh and accesskey.

Comment: But I don't think there's a problem with my page because it runs just fine with the other Android versions. Except they changed something in the Android HTTP request methods.

Comment: I maybe have to add, the login window opens and the user can grant my app access to his Spotify data. Then, when I normally receive the Spotify response, it just happens nothing. And as I said, the problem only occurs if I install it via the Playstore.